# Flutter Widget Inspector - Not displaying

Tags: flutter

I am using Android Studio 3.1.3 and my flutter inspector doesn't show anything in it.

https://flutter.io/inspector/#flutter-widget-inspector

select widget button etc... are not appearing.(However flutter outline is wokring)

I have installed both flutter and dart plugins.

Comment: This looks like a bug. Are you willing to file a bug at https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/new?

Answer (score 29):

1. Android Studio > Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Flutter > App Execution > Open Flutter Inspector view on launch
2. Close and Relaunch Android Studio > Open any Flutter Project > Open iOS Simulator or Android Emulator and Run Debug Mode
3. View > Tool Window > Flutter Inspector

PS: In order for something to show up in the Flutter Inspector, your app has to be running on a Device or on a Simulator or Emulator.

Comment: IMPORTANT: the app has to be in debug mode, profile mode does not work with Flutter Inspector

Comment: I'm running windows app with this command: `flutter run -d windows` and i cant get the inspector to work..

Comment: Make sure you open the devtools URL in Chrome!

Answer (score 4):

To make Flutter Widget Inspector work.

1. Run the App.
2. Check the emulator/simulator which screen is on.
3. Select the respected file from the Left side - Project Explorer

And you will be able to see the Flutter Widget Inspector working :)

P.s. It is still not working, Select RenderTree or Performance and then Widget. It will get refreshed. This is how it is working at my end.

Comment: tried that but couldn't get this to work. I don't even see the Widgets, Render Tree buttons

Comment: I didn't even realize I had to run the app for the inspector to work.  Their "intro to using the inspector" should say that first thing!

Answer (score 3):

The following steps helped me to get Flutter Inspector Widget Tree back:

File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Flutter:

Enable (Check) "Open Flutter Inspector view on app launch" checkbox

Disable (Uncheck) "Disable tracking widget creation locations" checkbox

Stop, start the app again.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and looks like toggling on and off **Show repaint Rainbow** is fixing it and renders the widget tree.
[image: Flutter Performance screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

This helped me get it back to work in VSCode.

1. Stop the emulator if you are running the app.
2. Run `flutter clean` in your terminal
3. Run the app again.
4. Open Command Palette in VS Code by pressing `F1`
5. Search for `Dart: Open Dev Tools` and click enter
6. Click `Open Widget Inspector Page`

The Widget Inspector will now display the Widget Tree.

Comment: I still get a blank widget inpector page. Is there anything else you did ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a real device to debug like me, try to open another virtual imulatior/emulator on your computer you can close it as soon as it's opened, it will wake up your sleeping inspector in VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having same issue with flutter 2.10.5. I think this is a bug related to flutter plugin. alternatively, you can use Flutter inspector on browser by clicking Flutter Performance Tab, Open Devtools

Answer (score 0):

A very rough but always valid fix is to change to a different version of the SDK (and then back, if necessary).

```
flutter channel master && flutter channel stable
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Flutter inspection is not working, all suggested workarounds above already tested.

Android 2021.3.1 Patch 1
Flutter installer 3.3.6-stable

Error:

[image]

When I click in the suggested link:

[image]

My Current Android Installation:

[image]

My hardware is a M1 MacBook Pro 8GB, 512HD, no issues into running the app itself, just the Inspector not working.

Any Ideas? Should I make this into a Question? I preferred to keep in the thread.

Comment: Found the solution to my problem. I uncheck the "Languages & Framework -> Fluttter -> Enable embedding DevTools in the Flutter Inspection tool window" and everything started working. I guess this is a beta feature and came already checked. I could be wrote and marked myself. BTW, a full clone and open is necessary after this change.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error after several tests, comparing the configuration files I realized that the error was in my launch.json configuration file.

```
   "version": "0.2.0",
 "settings": [
     {
         "name": "main",
         "type": "dart",
         "request": "launch",
         "program": "lib/main.dart"
     },
     {
         "name": "portal_amazonas Debug",
         "request": "launch",
         "type": "dart",
         "args": [
             "--flavor",
             "portal_amazonas"
         ],
         "program": "lib/flavors/main_portal_amazonas.dart"
     },
     {
         "name": "portal_amazonas",
         "request": "launch",
         "type": "dart",
         "flutterMode": "profile",
         "args": [
             "--flavor",
             "portal_amazonas"
         ],
         "program": "lib/flavors/main_portal_amazonas.dart"
     },
     {
         "name": "control_care Debug",
         "request": "launch",
         "type": "dart",
         "args": [
             "--flavor",
             "control_care"
         ],
         "program": "lib/flavors/main_control_care.dart",
     },
     {
         "name": "control_care",
         "request": "launch",
         "type": "dart",
         "flutterMode": "profile",
         "args": [
             "--flavor",
             "control_care"
         ],
         "program": "lib/flavors/main_control_care.dart",
     },

     {
         "name": "Run all tests",
         "type": "dart",
         "request": "launch",
         "program": "test/",
     },
 ]
```

}

See that the parameter "flutterMode": "profile" which could be "flutterMode": "debug", or "flutterMode": "release",

After removing this parameter everything returned to normal.

OBS: in my case I have flavors configured

Answer (score 0):

My solution here:

1. go 'preference' > 'setting'
2. type 'flutter' to search
3. in 'Dart' > 'DevTools' > 'Open Dev Tools'
4. select 'flutter'.
5. re-debug the application

[image: preference>setting>search flutter]