# Flutter Inspector and Widget Tree not loading in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I have installed latest version of Android Studio as well as all the necessary plugins such as Dart and Flutter. When I run an application and hit the Flutter Inspector tab on the right side of the screen, the Flutter Inspector window pops up with a message saying "The JxBrowser license could not be found".

[image: The JxBrowser license could not be found]

I have tried all the workarounds indicated in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51181774/flutter-widget-inspector-not-displaying) but were to no avail.
Is there anything I missed about the JxBrowser or something?

Comment: This was recently fixed: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/6463

Answer (score 2):

I've experienced the same message. But I think I've found a temporal way to use the inspector on Android Studio without `Layout Explorer` (Visualization part for widgets) before Flutter team fixing it.

Go to Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Flutter and **uncheck** `Enable embedding DevTools in the Flutter Inspector tool window`
[image]

Then you can use it without Layout Explorer inside Android Studio.
But, if you have to use such a Layout Explorer, then you can use the DevTools in the browser.